# How to autoscale azure data explorer(ADX) kusto cluster (optimized/custom) using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-explorer

I am doing automation of creating adx kusto cluster creation using python with azure cli module. I could be able to create a cluster with the specified capacity. but I have no idea how to implement auto-scale in/out. how do I achieve in python?

```
if get_default_cli().invoke(['kusto', 'cluster', 'create', '--name', name, '--sku', sku, '--resource-group', resource_group, '--capacity', capacity]) == 0:
    print("Kusto Cluster " + name + " Created Successfully")
else:
    print("Something went wrong while creating ADX Cluster")
    get_default_cli().invoke(['logout'])
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ADX python library to create and manage your Kusto cluster and don't need to construct the request yourself. Take the latest version from here:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-kusto/0.3.0/

You can then create a cluster this way:

```
cluster_operations.create_or_update(resource_group_name, cluster_name, cluster)
```

One of the parameter is an "optimizedAutoscale" which you can configure to ask ADX to automatically scale out/in your cluster within a range you choose.

See also my blog here which describes how to do that using REST API:
https://radennis.github.io/Ravit-Blog/blogs/UseRestToEnableOptimizedAutoscale.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom autoscale with ADX, please refer to the autoscale CLI within Azure Monitor CLI.  The same autoscale CLI applies to all Azure resources including Cloud Services, Virtual Machine Scale Sets, App Services, and ADX.  The only change you make is to set the target resource ID to be the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) resource ID of your ADX cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/autoscale?view=azure-cli-latest

If optimize autoscale in ADX meets your scenario/requirements, then my recommendation is to go with optimized autoscale as it's simpler to setup and leaves the configuration to ADX team to manage.  However, if you need more control over the autoscaling configuration, you can go with custom autoscale via Azure Monitor.